# Polymer: Displaying a dialog

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use a Polymer paper-dialog to display a message in response to an external event and am having difficulty even with a simple case. I'm getting an error saying 'this.$: undefined' (see code below).

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">

<dom-module id="dialogtest-main">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog id='goodbyeDialog' modal>
            <p> Goodbye! </p>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>

        <p align="center">Hello...</p>
    </template>
    <script>
    doTimer = function() {
        element.openDialog();
    }

    element = {
        is: "dialogtest-main",
        ready: function() {
            window.setTimeout(doTimer, 1000);
            console.log("ready");
        },
        openDialog: function() {
            console.log("opening dialog");
            this.$.goodbyeDialog.open();
        }
    };
    Polymer(element);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I have made a few desperate stabs by placing a breakpoint in the openDialog function and executing in the console:

```
this.$
```

undefined

```
this.$.goodbyeDialog
```

TypeError: this.$ is undefined

```
element.$.goodbyeDialog
```

TypeError: element.$ is undefined

```
document.getElementById("goodbyeDialog")
```

< paper-dialog modal="" id="goodbyeDialog" class="style-scope dialogtest-main x-scope paper-dialog-0" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-modal="true" style="outline: medium none; display: none;">

```
document.getElementById("goodbyeDialog").open()
```

undefined

```
document.getElementById("goodbyeDialog").toggle()
```

undefined

Any ideas? I'm sure I must be doing something very simple wrong!

Comment: Why do you want to use `window.setTimeout`, why not directly call `this.openDialog()` from either `ready` event or `attached` ?

Comment: I would like advise you to study JavaScript scoping and read the Polymer documentation especially the [life cycle](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks) part. Otherwise you'll get this kind of issues frequently.

Comment: @Mason, will do - more reading is definitely needed to avoid this in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `this` context to the methods `doTimer` and `element.openDialog` for this `paper-dialog` to work in this scenario. Here is the working example

I would suggest you to directly use `this.openDialog()` from `ready` or `attached` event of the element instead of `window.setTimeout`.

Polymer way of open the `paper-dialog` after a timeout would be using [async](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-async) which will run the callback function bound to `this`. You can replace `window.setTimeout(doTimer.bind(this), 1000);` with `this.async(this.openDialog, 1000);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>

  <title>Paperdialog-test</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  
   <link rel="import" href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
   
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">
  <dialogtest-main></dialogtest-main>

<dom-module id="dialogtest-main">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog id='goodbyeDialog' modal>
            <p> Goodbye! </p>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>

        <p align="center">Hello...</p>
    </template>
    <script>
    doTimer = function() {
        element.openDialog.call(this);
    }

    element = {
        is: "dialogtest-main",
        ready: function() {
            window.setTimeout(doTimer.bind(this), 1000);
            console.log("ready");
        },
        openDialog: function() {
            console.log("opening dialog");
            this.$.goodbyeDialog.open();
        }
    };
    Polymer(element);
    </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For `setTimeout`, that should be `doTimer.bind(this)` to get a callback. `doTimer.call(this)` invokes the function immediately.

Comment: And `element.openDialog.call(this)` is equivalent to `this.openDialog()`.

Comment: @tony19 `doTimer.call(this)` changed to `doTimer.bind(this)`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks guys. It was only a very trivial example of what I need to do, but that works a treat!